# Recommendation on building a browser app for visualizing data in a database for within the company?

Tags: python, database, ms-access, web-applications, visualization

I'm looking for a solution for this intended application.

I maintain a database of performance of a list of companies in our investment portfolio. The database is a collection of the company's daily performance, going back a few months. The format of the table is as follows (simplified version):

```
ID, Date, Investment_Name, Market_Share, %_change
1, 1/1/2000, SPX, 0.1, 0.05
2, 1/1/2000, INDU, 0.2, -0.01
...
101, 1/2/2000, SPX, 0.1, 0.03
102, 1/2/2000, INDU, 0.2, 0.03
...
```

The data is maintained in Access currently and I have queries setup for myself to see things like daily return for the whole portfolio, get historical series for selected securities, etc. Basically anything I can think of that I can make a query for.

..

Now I'm trying to create something for other people to access this data. I want it to be an application (hosted on our local network), that gives people an idea for our company's current performance. The simplest thing I could think of is to make a browser app that queries the database and gives visualization of the data. The user can have the freedom to select things they want to look at, in both table and graph form. Maybe make a few modules that displays "top 5" "bottom 5" in each asset class. More advanced feature would be making "what if" scenarios, changing security composition and things like that.

My experience in development is quite limited. I know python to a workable extent, have used things like pandas and matplotlib for local graphing. I'm wondering if there's a lightweight way to set up a system like this using some other python modules? Or is there a web framework already available for this type of task? I'm sure this is a common task in many organization and I'd love to know what's the easiest way to accomplish this.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various opensource BI tools, the major players are:

- http://www.pentaho.com/
- http://www.actuate.com/products/open-source-bi/
- http://community.jaspersoft.com/

It's not just about a tool though, do you want to keep the data in Access or do you want to put it in something like mysql or postgresql, how will you automate the ETL (see also http://www.talend.com), document the definitions etc.

Building it yourself is cooler, but also not that easy. You could build a RESTful api on pandas (running on UWSGI/Flask for instance) and then put a html5 library like d3.js (http://d3js.org) on top of it. But that's a really large effort, especially for a one man team. I would look at pentaho if i were you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to load the data into a shared database (using any version of SQL, in your case SQL Server most likely as you're starting in Access) and then slapping something like Spotfire (http://spotfire.tibco.com/) or Tableau (http://www.tableausoftware.com/) on top of that.  I've used Tableau and it's pretty slick, you can pre-can some reports as well as allow your users to manipulate the data in real time.  It also has a web interface that I've never used.

Both are a bit pricy though so I don't know if that will work for you.  Good luck!

Comment: Both look really cool but I dont have any funding haha... I'm just a one man team. Any open source alternative you can think of?

Comment: Nothing that I know of, if you want you can try googling for "business intelligence" solutions and you may find something.  If you do I'd like to hear about it as well!

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily exactly what you wanting, but may accomplish most of the same goals, depending on security concerns, on-site requirements, etc...

Google has a beta product they've incorporated into their Google Drive product called Fusion Tables.  It is basically a simple, streamlined, cloud hosted database engine.  It supports SQL based updating via url or manual updating within the interface.  Furthermore, it has a number of visualization capabilities built into it.  Depending on how secure you need it to be, and/or if you already have google apps for business, that might be an option to look into.

You could just set up a new fusion table (get Google account, sign in, go to google drive, and click create, and there should be a table or fusion table or some such as that as a create option).  You could then create the fields and manually add the data or just import the existing table you already have.  Then edit the sharing properties to give others, as necessary, just read only permissions or read and write permissions to the table and the various visualization you can creat from it.  There are some charting and graphing capabilities built in though I haven't played around with that side too much myself as I've mainly used it's integrated mapping capabilities.

Again, not perfect solution for what you were asking for, but thought it might help, so figured I'd share.

Comment: This is very interesting. I'm checking it out right now. Something I can't quite figure is how scalable this solution is. I think the upper bound of how many data points I could go up to is 500k a year. I assume Google as the data giant could take care of something on this magnitude for a small client's need.